# Python YouTube Gdata Player Error

Tags: python, youtube, gdata

I'm trying something really simple: get a list of player urls from the youtube gdata module,

```
def getlist():
  index = 1
  prev = 0
  urls = []
  while True:
    uri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/E005D335B57338D1?start-index=%i&max-results=50" % index
    feed = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(uri)
    for entry in feed.entry:
      urls.append(entry.media.player.url)
    if prev == len(urls): break
    prev = len(urls)
    index += 50
  return urls
```

However, the following error occurs when calling getlist:

```
>>> urls = getlist()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    getlist()
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 9, in getlist
    urls.append(entry.media.player.url)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'
```

I have no idea why this is happening, it worked a couple weeks ago...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a check to guarantee that the player is not null:

```
...
for entry in feed.entry:
  if entry.media.player is not None:
    urls.append(entry.media.player.url)
...
```